# Search bar React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, material-ui, searchbar

I need to create search bar for my app. I'm using currently `react-native-material-ui` ,[this](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui#examples), but I have problems.

1- It causes delay on the real device.

2- How can I search the items in that "search bar". I have this code on my render method:

```
<View style={{marginBottom: 50}}>
    <ThemeProvider uiTheme={uiTheme}>
        <Toolbar uiTheme={uiTheme}
                 leftElement="arrow-back"
                 onLeftElementPress={() => goBack()}
                 centerElement={params.tapName}
                 searchable={{
                       autoFocus: true,
                       placeholder: 'Search',
                       onChangeText: (text) => {    
                               this.setState({currentSearch: text});
                               for (var i = 0; i < this.state.brands.length; i++) {  
if(this.state.brands[i].name.search(text) != -1)                            
     console.warn(this.state.brands[i].name);}},
                                }}
                              />
       </ThemeProvider>
    </View>
```

I can find the names of the brands, but I couldn't filter them and render them. If you know how to render those filtered items, or know better search bar, I'm waiting your answers.

Comment: you should not be able to access state variables in `onChangeText`

Comment: you can add your search code into another function and call in `onChangeText`.

Answer (score 0):

replace `onChangeText` with

```
onChangeText={(text) => this.searchItem({text})}
```

and add one function `searchItem` and place your search logic inside this function.

```
searchItem(text) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.brands.length; i++) {  
            if(this.state.brands[i].name.search(text) != -1)                            
                console.warn(this.state.brands[i].name);
        }
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm using two state variables: `initialData` and `filteredData`. In initial state I have assigned main source data to both variables.

Using `filteredData` as `datasource`. Once user search compare `text` with `initialData`. If you have matching result then create an array and update `filteredData` with that result.

If you want to clear the filtered result then assign main source `initialData` to `filteredData`.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: fly... I have created custom searchbar.

Comment: it does not filter the brands. I can see as warning that they are filtered, but in render part, they are not filtered.

Comment: You need to update your initial listing state with filtered result.

Comment: How can I achieve that? I'm generating the list while I'm loading the page, componentDidMount method. After that, whenever I try to use the names, list items, I call them as {this.state.name}. How can I update this?

Comment: I have two state variables, one keeps original data, and another have filtered data, initially I'm assigning original data to filtered data then once user type, in search function I am comparing with original data and update filtered data with searched result.

Comment: @dolares Please accept my answer if this helped you. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this out. I couldn't manage to do it with you way, so I looked up for another methods.


 onChangeText: (text) => {
                    
    this.state.brands.filter(function(text){
                     
    console.warn('Warn Me!');
                     
    //console.warn(this.state.brands);  //I cannot use this because it says that  Undefined is not an object(evaluating this.state.brands)
                   })               
                  },
As I said, I generated the list while loading the page and assigned that array of list to the state.